# How to add keyListener to the ViewPart

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I try to add possibility to close view on ESC button. I have a view NewsContentView and try to add key listener to it by this way

```
this.addListenerObject(new KeyListener() {

   @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.keyCode == SWT.ESC){
                IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                activePage.hideView(activePage.findView(ID));
            }
        }
    });
```

but get the error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.forexgame.ui.views.NewsContentView$1 cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.IPropertyListener
>       at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.firePropertyChange(WorkbenchPart.java:127)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.internalSetPartName(WorkbenchPart.java:466)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.setPartName(WorkbenchPart.java:384)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart.setPartName(ViewPart.java:129)
>       at com.forexgame.ui.views.NewsContentView.setName(NewsContentView.java:88)
>       at com.forexgame.ui.views.NewsView.showNewsContentView(NewsView.java:133)
>       at com.forexgame.ui.views.NewsView.access$0(NewsView.java:121)
>       at com.forexgame.ui.views.NewsView$1.doubleClick(NewsView.java:92)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:832)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:829)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDoubleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1150)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1263)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>       at com.forexgame.application.Application.start(Application.java:20)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

Also I looked for opportunity to add Key Listener to the active page, but IWorkBenchPage interface have no such methods and has only methods

```
                    activePage.addPartListener(IPartListener listener);
                activePage.addPartListener(IPartListener2 listener);
                activePage.addPostSelectionListener(ISelectionListener listener);
                activePage.addPostSelectionListener(String partId, ISelectionListener listener);
                activePage.addSelectionListener(ISelectionListener listener);
                activePage.addSelectionListener(String partId, ISelectionListener listener);
                activePage.addPropertyChangeListener(IPropertyChangeListener listener);
```

Why this error is occurs and whether there is a diffent way to add key listener on a view?

Comment: Key events are always sent to the current control so you would have to add a key listener to every control in the view

Comment: greg-449 Thanks a lot! Everything workes. Could you please suggest which book or an articles should I read to learn such common things? How did you find out about this?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't looked at tutorials or books in a long time.